# Using gulp-sequence with gulp plumber

Tags: error-handling, return, gulp, sequence

I have run into a strange problem regarding using gulp-sequence with gulp-plumber. For gulp-plumber to stop the "gulp watch" task from breaking when an error is encountered the gulp task needs to have the "return" removed from the beginning of the task.

For e.g (return that needs to be removed in caps )

```
gulp.task('sass:dev', function() {   
    RETURN gulp.src(assets_sass)
        .pipe(plugins.plumber({
            handleError: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
                this.emit('end');
            }
        }))
        .pipe(plugins.sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dist_css));
});
```

When running a sequence using gulp-sequence that return is needed so that the sequence knows when the task is done. Otherwise the sequence will simply run all tasks at the same time.

I could do two separate tasks for watch and build but this seems like a terrible solution.

Anybody have any ideas to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plumber can be called with two options, one of them is 'errorHandler' - [ref](https://github.com/floatdrop/gulp-plumber#optionserrorhandler). I am returning the stream to run this task sequentially and its working fine.

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src('public/css/*.scss')
    .pipe(plumber({
      errorHandler: function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        this.emit('end');
      }
    }))
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))
    .pipe(rename({
      suffix: '.min'
    }))
    .pipe(minifycss())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))
});
```

Comment: Wow, so changing "handleError" to "errorHandler" solved the problem. I'm guessing the difference is that the errorHandler allows the task to continue running so doesn't break the watch task. Thanks!